# Rate button in my main.xml

Tags: java, android

I want to add one button to my main.xml for redirecting the user to rate my app. 
i am programming my activity with a switch method cause i have a lot of buttons doing differents things, but i don't know how to make a button to rate my app.

If someone can give me an example.

thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 2):

You can set an `Intent` to get into your [application's page in the market app](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent).

```
http://market.android.com/search?q=pub:<Developer Name>
```

or

`market://search?q=pub:<Developer Name>`

Comment: Don't forget to wrap this between a try/catch statement. On devices without Android Market, your application would crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can't show "rate" dialog for user. Only possible way is to ask user if he wants it and open page of your app on market:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName())));
```

Comment: Don't forget to wrap this between a try/catch statement. On devices without Android Market, your application would crash.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the answer of Rotemmiz, this is a method I have in a Helper class for my applications:

```
  public static void openMarketAppPage(Context context) {
    String packageName = context.getApplicationInfo().packageName;
    try {
        // Open the market application on your app page
        Uri marketAppUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketAppUri);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // If no market application on the device, open the market website instead
        Uri marketWebUri = Uri.parse("http://market.android.com/details?id=" + packageName);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketWebUri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
  }
```

Comment: this is nice, but i want to add a button on your codes. with my switch.

Comment: Google helps a lot lazy coders: http://www.connorgarvey.com/blog/?p=93